# How to pass a list to APIFunction?

Tags: api, parameters

My problem is I have a list of 170 values.  To use API function, I had to represent these values by 170 parameters (not the most elegant thing).  My question is, can I pass a list to APIFunction, or how do I pass a list to a APIFunction?
Any help will be most appreciated.

For instance,  I want to add a list of numbers

```
    func = APIFunction[{"x" -> "List"}, Total[#x] &]
```

but when I run it I get the following

```
    func[<|"x" -> {1, 2, 3, 4}|>]
```

I the function returns 4 instead of 10

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer in here

https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1055892

```
 api1 = APIFunction["x" -> RepeatingElement["Integer"], Max[#d]&]
```

But instead of a list, I decided to pass a string and just change it to a list in the function.

As characters takes less space than numbers, this worked just fine.
If anyone is interested the code is here https://github.com/DalilaR/PredictingCreditScore